# Wrong namespaces assigned by PHP SOAP Client

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have little to no experience in SOAP. And I am interacting with a third party wsdl web service. For this I use PHP's native SoapClient.

When I send the request I'm getting an error response that states the following:

```
Schema validation failed: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: Content of element 'ns2:ScheduleP' is not complete. '{"http://blabla.com/webservices/offer/request":List}' is expected.
```

The relevant parts of the autogenerated XML are as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

    xmlns:ns1="http://blabla.com/webservices/offer/request"
    xmlns:ns2="http://blabla.com/webservices/datatypes/data"
    xmlns:ns3="http://blabla.com/webservices/offer/response"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:OfferRequest>
        <ns1:Header us="my-user" sig="42fc731ee1f1c1" tnr="532709" t="20220301120026"/>
        <ns1:RequestData>
            <ns1:ScheduleP  xsi:type="ns3:Schedule">
                <ns3:List>
                    <ns3:Item/>
                </ns3:List>
            </ns1:ScheduleP>
        </ns1:RequestData>
        </ns1:OfferRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I take the autogenerated XML, change the namespace alias for the List and Item nodes from ns3 to ns1, and send it through postman, it works like a charm.

I think the problem is that both the ns1 namespace and ns2 namespace have a specification for a ScheduleP, List and Item. and the PHP SoapClient is assigning the wrong namespace alias to the List and Item nodes.

Just for clarification, this is the XML that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

    xmlns:ns1="http://blabla.com/webservices/offer/request"
    xmlns:ns2="http://blabla.com/webservices/datatypes/data"
    xmlns:ns3="http://blabla.com/webservices/offer/response"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:OfferRequest>
        <ns1:Header us="my-user" sig="42fc731ee1f1c1" tnr="532709" t="20220301120026"/>
        <ns1:RequestData>
            <ns1:ScheduleP  xsi:type="ns3:Schedule">
                <ns1:List>
                    <ns1:Item/>
                </ns1:List>
            </ns1:ScheduleP>
        </ns1:RequestData>
        </ns1:OfferRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have no idea on how to proceed, how can one fix this miss-assignation of namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
Since I have a class that extends PHP's SoapClient, I can override the __doRequest() function which receives the generated XML String as its first parameter, then you can apply any modification to that string and finally call  parent::__doRequest() to send it.